# Using PyTelegramBotAPI to read messages without using / command to call

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to use the pyTelegramBotAPI to get scores for a game me and my friends play from our chat but I want to use regex to filter the messages and only read the ones with the scores in them so no one has to worry about using the commands or super proper formatting or anything like that.

I've tried using commands like

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_messages(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
```

But this will only read when a message has a '/' in front of it. This might not even be possible but I am not great with the API message handler commands so I might be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to untoggle privacy mode from [@BotFather](https://t.me/botfather) on telegram.
/mybots -> select the bot -> Bot Settings -> Group Privacy -> Turn off

By default setting, every bot is created with privacy mode turned on, so that the bot only receives updates that are commands( and start with '/')
It comes handy sometimes, so that you don't have to worry that people may mess up with your bot, but keep in mind to turn it off on almost every bot.

Sorry for bad english